# ffmpeg codec libx264 file size limit

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg libx264 a lot when I share videos on discord and I'd like the script to adjust the quality based on the target size limit of discord, which is about 12 mb, is it possible?

this is usually my go to script
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 45 %random%%random%.mp4

Comment: I don't think there is a direct option for setting a target size limit like 12MB. According to [H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264), we can set the average bitrate. That mean that we have to know the video duration, and set the average bitrate in such way that bitrate*duration < "file size in bits". The container (like MP4) adds some overhead. The audio stream also has a bitrate. Using Two-Pass encoding may help when targeting a specific output file size.